# Why is the reported user "root" when a "normal user" executes "ps ux" on OS X? Is this normal behaviour?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, root, user, ps

I am running OS X 10.6.1 .
When i am logged in as a normal user of group staff and do a

```
ps ux
```

it lists my ps ux command as being run by root:

```
snies   181   0.0  0.3  2774328  12500   ??  S     6:00PM   0:20.96 /System/Library...
root   1673   0.0  0.0  2434788    508 s001  R+    8:16AM   0:00.00 ps ux
snies   177   0.0  0.0  2457208    984   ??  Ss    6:00PM   0:00.52 /sbin/launchd
snies  1638   0.0  0.0  2435468   1064 s001  S     8:13AM   0:00.03 -bash
```

Is this normal behaviour? And if so why?
Please note that the user is not an Administrator account and is not able to sudo.

Comment: Anyone with 10.5 and earlier? Has it always been like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is normal for Mac OS X. It used to be normal on almost all Unix-oid systems. It runs as root without *sudo* because the *ps* binary is set-uid to run as root (e.g. on my 10.4 system):

```
% ls -l $(which ps)
-rwsr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  31932 Mar 20  2005 /bin/ps
```

(the `s` in place of the the user-owner `x` column means that it is set-uid (and user-executable), the owner is root; this means that no matter who runs it, it will run as root)

Traditionally (and still the case on Mac OS X systems), it must run as root because the information it needs is only available via root-accessible devices (e.g. /dev/kmem) or root-only system calls. This is OK because (unless there are bugs in the implementation) the *ps* program is written in a way that does not let callers get information that they should not otherwise have.

Other systems have other mechanisms that provide access to the info that *ps* needs and thus do not need set-uid *ps* binaries. Notably, the [/proc virtual filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) on Linux systems (and others) can publish very fine grained kernel information with equally fine grained permissions. Such a model is sufficient to allow a non-privileged *ps* to get everything it needs without allowing access to the more sensitive bits of kernel information.